Changes made in the WordPress database are not reflected on the live site
I am making link changes within some posts that I have on a site. I have made the changes and checked them in the database, and everything seems perfect; however, these changes are not being reflected on the live site or in wp-admin when I edit with Elementor.
When I use the HTML code editor of the default WordPress editor, the link changes appear, but as I mentioned, the live site remains with the old links.

I have cleared the browser cache.
I deactivated the site's cache plugin in WordPress.
I cleared the site cache in wp-admin.
In the Elementor plugin, I have used the options: Regenerate CSS and     data, Sync library, and saved the changes.

None of these actions have had an effect.
Update
When I look in the Wordpress HTML editor, the links are all changed to the right url. View image.
html code edit
However, when I look in the Elementor editor it still has the old url. View image.
Elementor edit

Please double check the URL you are editing. There are times where users edit a temporary domain without noticing. Other solution its to flush the server cache. If this doesn't work, then contact the server directly to find the issue.
I hope this helps!
